# Using a custom theme inside a zip file

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have my sphinx documentation set up and want to use a custom theme. I have read the theme instructions on the sphinx website: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html, but it doesn't work.

I have my theme name the same as it is in the `conf.py` file and it is in a zip folder in the same directory, but i keep getting the following error:

```
Theme error:
no theme named 'tera' found (missing theme.conf?)
make: *** [html] Error 2
```

My conf.py code is:

```
html_theme = "tera"

html_theme_options = {

}

html_theme_path = ['.']
```

As per the instructions, I have got a `theme.conf` file in the `.zip` file along with everything else I need. Not sure how to fix.

In my theme.conf file I have:

```
[theme] 
inherit = basic 
stylesheet = css/Terra.css 
pygments_style = default
```

File structure is as follows: Documents > Documentation >_themes. Inside themes I have a 'tera' folder and a 'tera.zip' file.

I've also tried just putting the tera.zip file in my documentation folder directly, so its in the same directory as the conf.py file and still no luck

Comment: Is it a .zip file or a folder/directory? Your question says "zip folder", which is confusing. Please include your directory and file structure, as well as the contents of your `theme.conf`.

Comment: In my theme.conf file I have:                                                                                      
                                                                                                         [theme]
inherit = basic
stylesheet = css/Terra.css
pygments_style = default

File structure is as follows:               
Documents > Documentation >_themes.                                           
Inside themes I have a 'tera' folder and a 'tera.zip' file

Comment: I've also tried just putting the tera.zip file in my documentation folder directly, so its in the same directory as the conf.py file and still no luck

Comment: What's inside tera.zip?

Comment: theme.conf file and the '_static' folder with my css and images

Comment: I think theme.conf must be at the root of the directory structure inside the zip file. Is that true in your case?

Comment: Yep, that's what I've currently got

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions and I am unable to reproduce the problem. Sorry. I think a [mcve] is needed (a GitHub project, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I currently had the same problem. My issue was that `zip` creates by default a directory inside the zip file, thus `theme.conf` is not in its root.

Doing

```
$ zip -r tera.zip tera/*
```

gives the following:

```
$ less tera.zip
... Name
... ----
... tera/theme.conf
```

where I truncated the uninteresting output (`...`). If you do however

```
$ cd tera
$ zip -r tera.zip *
```

the configuration file will be at the root and sphinx works.

Comment: This does not appear to be the OP's problem. theme.conf is already at the root of the directory structure inside the zip file. See the comments to the question.

Comment: It is likely that this is not the problem in the post. I thought it is good to post it here nevertheless, as this is what you find if you google the problem. I got the same error because I thought it is enough to have `theme.conf` at the root. Maybe it helps someone else.